# ReactJS what is the proper way to wait for prop to load to avoid crashing my page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-props

all,

I am building a local website for myself for stocks. Currently I have a store that communicates with my tomcat instance to get stock market data, this works flawlessly.

on my frontend I am attempting to display my data but sometimes it works, sometimes it does not work and I get an "this child prop does not exist" so this is what I implemented:

```
try{
          cellRend = this.cellRenderer;
          columnLen = this.props.selectedStock.Revenue.length;
          this.state.isLoading = false
        }catch(error){ 
           cellRend = this.cellRendererEmpty;  
           columnLen = 10;
        }
        if (this.state.isLoading === true){
            return <div>Loading!</div>
        }
```

where cellRenderer is my table, cellRendererEmpty is an empty table.

this kind of works and some times it will just display Loading! forever. so my question is what is the correct way to wait for a prop?

here is my full code:

```
const dispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return{
      getSelStock: (stockId) => dispatch(stockActions.getSelStock(stockId))  
    };
}


class stockPage extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            columnLen:10,
            data:null,
            isLoading:true
        }
        console.log(this.props.isLoading)
        this.cellRenderer = this.cellRenderer.bind(this);
        this.render = this.render.bind(this);
    }
    
    cellRenderer({ columnIndex, key, rowIndex, style }) {   
            return (
      <div className={"app"} key={key} style={style}>
          <span></span>
        {rowIndex === 0 ? (`${this.props.selectedStock.Revenue[columnIndex].date}`) : (
          <span>{`${this.props.selectedStock.Revenue[columnIndex].value}`}</span>
        )}
      </div>
    );
        
    }
    
    cellRendererEmpty({ columnIndex, key, rowIndex, style }) {
            return (
      <div className={"app"} key={key} style={style}>
        {rowIndex === 0 ? (`${columnIndex}`) : (
          <span>{`${columnIndex}`}</span>
        )}
      </div>
    );
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    render() { 
        var cellRend, columnLen
                console.log("Hey")
       this.props.getSelStock(this.props.match.params.stockId);        
        try{
          cellRend = this.cellRenderer;
          columnLen = this.props.selectedStock.Revenue.length;
          this.state.isLoading = false
        }catch(error){ 
           cellRend = this.cellRendererEmpty;  
           columnLen = 10;
        }
        if (this.state.isLoading === true){
            return <div>Loading!</div>
        }
        return(
                
                <div>
                <h1>{this.props.match.params.stockId}</h1>
                    <AutoSizer disableHeight>
      {({ width }) => (
        <MultiGrid
          cellRenderer={cellRend}
          columnWidth={125}
          columnCount={this.state.columnLen}
          enableFixedColumnScroll ={1}
          enableFixedRowScroll ={1}
          fixedColumnCount
          fixedRowCount
          height={300}
          rowHeight={70}
          rowCount={2}
          style={STYLE}
          styleBottomLeftGrid={STYLE_BOTTOM_LEFT_GRID}
          styleTopLeftGrid={STYLE_TOP_LEFT_GRID}
          styleTopRightGrid={STYLE_TOP_RIGHT_GRID}
          width={width}
          hideTopRightGridScrollbar
          hideBottomLeftGridScrollbar
          hideBottomRightGridScrollbar
        />
      )}
    </AutoSizer>
        </div>
                )
    
    
    }
    
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, dispatchToProps)(stockPage);
```

Comment: `this.state.isLoading = false` is wrong. You can't mutate the state like that. Do a `setState()` call.

Comment: your right I forgot,I updated it to this.setState({isLoading: false}) and the issue persists, sometimes it works other it does not (it will work on my local laptop for example but not my phone/other PC

Comment: also it will sometimes not work on my local machine as well it gets stuck on "loading"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your title, I assume that when your page loads, you are fetching data then you use that data in the page. However, during initial load and when your fetching is still in process, your data is still null and your app will crash because the code is expecting data to have a value which it needs to use...

What you can do is while the data is fetching, then do not display the rest of the page yet (ie. you can just display a giant spinner gif), then once the fetching is complete then update isLoading state... Or you can set an initial value for the data so the page won't crash on load...

EDIT:
so using react lifecycle fixed your problem as per your comment... anyways just wanna add that you may want to use async/await instead of setTimeout like you did in your comment.. This is what the code might look like for async/await in lifecycles...

```
componentDidMount() {
    const fetchData = async () {
        await this.props.getSelStock() // your dispatch

        // the state you want to update once the dispatch is done
        this.setState({isLoading: false}) 
    }

    fetchData();
}
```

Comment: thanks, in my first code snippet that is exactly what I am trying to do, but the issue is that sometimes it will stay on loading forever, and sometimes it will work. sometimes a manual refresh works etc... do you see anything that I am doing incorrectly? thanks!

Comment: Your first code snippet is in the render function, try to use componentDidMount on codes that you only want to run during initial page load. The logic for fetching data then setting isLoaded to true usually belongs there...

Comment: okay so I added     

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getSelStock(this.props.match.params.stockId); 
     setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ isLoading: 'false' });
    }, 6000);
  }

which just waits 6 seconds and it works, is there anyway to wait for the prop to load? Thanks for your help btw

Comment: if I understood correctly, it works as intended with setTimeout and you just want it so that instead of setTimeout, isLoading:false will run the moment the props is loaded?

Comment: yup exactly! the paren prop loads before the child, so how do I wait until the child loads? (I.e. this.selectedStock loads, but this.selectedStock.Revenue has not loaded yet)

Comment: to add to this I tried a few if state which did not work

Comment: NVM - using componentDidUpdate() makes it work flawlessly I hope this is the right way. thanks again for your help jove

Comment: great to hear that.. I edited my answer and included async/await in react lifecycle, you may want to try or fiddle with that instead of using setTimeout...